# Use AREPL within VScode using a WSL interpreter

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-venv

I have a WSL environment running python and venv.
Besides that I have VSCode running in Windows with AREPL

I have no problem accessing my python venv including pip modules using the VSCode terminal. AREPL however seems to fail to recognize my pip plugins. My guess is that AREPL is using the Windows Python version to run the code instantly. However the WSL python venv does not generate a python.exe I could point my AREPL interpreter to.

So my question is:

Can I run AREPL on Windows VSCode to validate code that requires PIP modules that are NOT installed in Windows, but are installed on WSL within a venv.

I've tried Changing AREPL Python Path to either Python venv, WSL or Windows Python:

```
"D:\Scripting\Python\venvs\automation\bin\python"
"C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe" (nothing happens as I type)
"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe" (generates error)
```

Error when using venv location:

```
Error in the AREPL extension!
Error running python with command:           D:\Scripting\Python\venvs\automation\bin\python -u C:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\almenon.arepl-1.0.16\node_modules\arepl-backend\python\python_evaluator.py
Error: spawn D:\Scripting\Python\venvs\automation\bin\python ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

Are you sure you have installed python 3 and it is in your PATH?
            You can download python here: https://www.python.org/downloads/
```

Error when using WSL:

```
Nothing happens
```

Error when using windows python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maker of AREPL here! Sorry I didn't see this until recently, hopefully it will still be helpful. To use WSL python in windows vscode you can set your pythonpath to JUST `wsl` and your pythonoptions to `["python3", "-u"]`. When you open it you will get ......

an error. Dang.

The problem is that the `python-shell` library I use uses `path.join` which joins the path to the arepl executor file with windows path separators, which doesn't work in WSL.

Instead of trying to run WSL python through windows vscode I suggest installing [remote-wsl](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl), opening a WSL vscode, installing the python and arepl extension there, and using that. I tested it and verified that it works.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time respond. Seems to work like a charm.

Comment: This doest not work with WSL version2. Any suggestions? Still getting the same error

Comment: @Florent to clarify you got the same error even when using [remote-wsl](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl), opening vscode in WSL, and running arepl there?

Comment: @Almenon I just was able to fix it. The problem was that the arepl extension searched for python on my windows OS, I had python installed but only on WSL2 and not on windows. I just had to change the python path in the arepl extension settings to the path on WSL2 and it worked. I use remote-wsl. Thanks for your extension, I love it!